# Name a variable by combining the contents of 2 variable

Tags: c#, forms, variables

I want when the user clicks the button a new variable will be created like now a variable should be created with the name 1time and when the user clicks again a new variable will be created with the name of 2time how can i do that please help me i am a beginner

```
int alltime = 1;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
        int alltime+time;
        alltime += 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't create variables at runtime. You can use appropriate types such as dictionaries.

Comment: Though you can store a collection of values in something like a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: What you probably want is a *list* or other collection to which you can add separate *values*.

Comment: All you are doing: is incrementing a value each time; you dont need an elaborate scheme for that.  Think about the value(s) stored

Comment: you can't, and trust me, you don't **want to**. and that's what all the collection-datatypes are for, like [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays), lists, dictionaries...

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to name a variable at runtime. C# does not support something like this. Names have to be choosen upfront.

If you want to match a value to a dynamic key, you could go with KeyValuePair<string, whateveryouwant> or a Dict<string, whateveryouwant>.

And to be honest. There is no case I can think of where it should be necessary to you use a dynamicly named variable.